# Error "Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted.."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have a model with over 100 properties with a primary key(Identity) that I use to insert or update the database using EF6 via Http Post with body.

I always get an error

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

whenever the values am passing from the controller to the model to be updated is different from whats in the database, but if the data in each column is the same as that from the model it saves perfectly using the below without issues.

And because the model properties are many, I don't want to be manually assigning the values to each property before calling the `SaveChanges()` method, even though doing that works

This is my Controller

```
[HttpPut("{autoid:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Store>> UpdateStore(int autoid, [FromBodyOrDefault]  Store store)
    {
        try
        {
            if (autoid != store.AutoId)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ID", "Auto ID mismatch");
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var response = await Store.StoreExists(store.AutoId);
            if (response != true)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("AutoId", $"Store with recordid:{autoid} not found");
                return NotFound(ModelState);
            }
                await Store.UpdateStore(store);
                return store;
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.InnerException.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And this is the UpdateStore Method

```
public async Task<int> UpdateStore(Store storeinfo)
{
        try
        {
            _context.Entry(storeinfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: How do you call `UpdateStore` method? How are you setting property values of model from controller?

Comment: I hit this issue when I changed the primary key on a table but did not update the mapping for the table in the code.